# Grid without background tapped event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a simple grid.
I want to handle Tapped event.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Tapped="PlanszaItemTapped"  />
```

But when Grid doesn't have any background the event don't respond.

This code working corectly but here is background.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Tapped="PlanszaItemTapped" Background="#FFF7F4F4" Opacity="0" />
```

I don't need this background. Opacity is 0 but when I make animation background is visible.

How to solve this issue?

Generaly my goal is to create Grid with 10 colum and 10 row and OnClick any Item just add image.

I use empty grids to respond the click event.

There is any shortest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Background="Transparent"` should be an option, otherwise I believe it's just the equivalent of `IsHitTestVisible="True"`